# Suspending an apache camel route depending of a folder content

Tags: java, apache-camel

I would like to decode this logic in an apache camel java app:
ReadFromActiveMq files and send them to direct route DirectRoute
    While existsFilesInFolder
    {
     retrytoLoadThemForever() //although errors appears --> manual action 
    required
    }
consume DirectRoute messages.

In java i have this made:

```
onManualDataReceivedException().maximumRedeliveries(-1)

from("file:" + recoverableErrorsFolder +"?noop=true").to("bean:processManualFilesDatabean");
//If there is an error in manual process i throw ManualDataReceivedException

from ("direct:DirectRoute")
        .to("bean:processDirectQueueBean");

private OnExceptionDefinition onManualDataReceivedException() {
   return onException(ManualDataReceivedException.class);
}
```

How can i pause direct:DirectRoute consumption if there are files in recoverableErrorsFolder folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ControlBus](https://camel.apache.org/controlbus.html) component to start/stop routes at runtime using their `routeId`.

This example shows how to stop a route while processing a file and restart it after processing. You can attach **start** action to `onCompletion` callbacks and implement a more robust logic.

```
from("direct:DirectRoute")
    .routeId("DR")       
    .to("bean:processDirectQueueBean");

from("file:" + recoverableErrorsFolder +"?noop=true")
    .to("controlbus:route?routeId=DR&action=stop")
    .to("bean:processManualFilesDatabean")
    .to("controlbus:route?routeId=DR&action=start");
```